# Directly passthru file stream from Google Cloud Storage to output in PHP

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to write a stream from Cloud Storage's `downloadAsStream()` function directly to the output. Every method I've tried so far returns a 'corrupt' image, which from what I can tell from the response size, is an empty image.

My current method of handling this first downloads the file into memory, then outputs it inefficiently. This does work, however.

```php
$storage = new Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient();
$bucket = $storage->bucket($bucketName);
$thumb = $bucket->object("thumb/Thumb-".$basename."-".$path[2].".jpg");
if ($thumb->exists()) {
    $size = $thumb->info()['size'];
    header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
    header("Content-Length: $size");
    echo $thumb->downloadAsString();
    die;
}
```

In the place of `echo $thumb->downloadAsString();` I have tried these alternatives, each with the same result:

```php
fpassthru($thumb->downloadAsStream());
```

```php
stream_copy_to_stream($thumb->downloadAsStream(), STDOUT);
```

```php
$stream = fopen("php://stdout", "w");
stream_copy_to_stream($thumb->downloadAsStream(), $stream);
```

```php
$stream = fopen("php://output", "w");
stream_copy_to_stream($thumb->downloadAsStream(), $stream);
flush();
```

I am using PHP 8.

Comment: Show the code that created $thumb.

Comment: @JohnHanley `$storage = new Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient();
$bucket = $storage->bucket($bucketName);
$thumb = $bucket->object("thumb/Thumb-".$basename."-".$path[2].".jpg");`

Comment: Edit your question with the code. Include the imports (use statements) and library version information.

Comment: Today, the version of PHP is important.

Comment: What's the actual size of the file you're trying to display? My understanding is that php may run out of memory when trying to stream an image.  

Do you have any error logs regarding this? Either in php itself or in Cloud Logging?